# Action header like Jabong mobile app

Tags: android, android-layout

I wish to achieve something like this:
[image]

My understanding is using card layout and I've tried a few things but didn't got view exactly like above. A brief idea will do it

Comment: Use LinearLayout with Buttons.

Comment: Look this question answer for raised button : https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2n0uij/getting_a_simple_raised_button/

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:layout_weight=".1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:layout_weight=".1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```